# consulta SQl con datos repetidos en un campo

Tags: sql

Como obtengo el ultimo registro de datos que se repiten en un campo en una consulta sql, por ejemplo tengo la siguiente tabla

[image: tabla]

el objetivo es que al final la consulta me arroje el siguiente resultado[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿El último significa aquel con la Nota más alta? si es así un con un `GROUP BY` y la función `MAX(Nota)` deberías poder solucionarlos.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho no, no con la nota mas alta, ya que las notas varian , si hay mas notas solo quiero obtener el ultimo registro que se ingreso.

Comment: En las bases de datos no existe el concepto de último o primero, por que eso es siempre relativo al orden que le demos a la consulta, con la información que muestras no es posible determinar cual podría ser orden para establecer   el último registro. Imagino que debieras tener una fecha o un id autonumerico que sirva para tal fin. Agrega la definición de la tabla. Saludos

Comment: Perdón.., de paso, bienvenido al Sitio!

Answer (score 0):

Hola mi recomendación es que crees una columna de fecha (FechaCreacion, por ejemplo), le des un valor al insertar el elemento (getdate()) y que cuando necesites el orden de inserción hagas un ORDER BY FechaCreacion.

Te quedaría algo así:

```
SELECT Id, Nombre, Nota, FechaCreacion
  FROM NombreTabla
  GROUP BY Id, Nombre, Nota, FechaCreacion
  ORDER BY FechaCreacion DESC
```

Saludos!